# How to open the native application to capture a video then return to my app once captured in Windows Phone 8 using C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, video, windows-phone-8

I want the user to be able to add attachments in my Windows Phone 8 application, they should be able to select 'capture video' which will open the phone's native video capturing application and then once the video is captured they will be returned to my app.

Comment: A nice article on implementing video capture - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198244.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, there is no VideoCapture task, you need to implement video capture feature within your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I feared that may be the case. Do you know if this is the same for Photos and Audio?